# EXPO Error: Fastlane build failed with unknown error

Tags: expo, fastlane, eas

I'm trying to compile my expo development (Not expo go) app, it all works for IOS and android in testing but when i try compiling it for production, only the android compiles successfully  the IOS build fails at "Run Fastlane".

I've search and tried different online suggestions but nothing seems to work
has anyone else run into this issue? I've been stuck for days

my error

```
Build failed: Fastlane build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run fastlane" and "Xcode Logs" phases for more information.
Fastlane errors in most cases are not printed at the end of the output, so you may not find any useful information in the last lines of output when looking for an error message.
```

here is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "myapp",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "iconIOS.png",
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "react-native-fbsdk-next",
        {
          "appID": "12",
          "clientToken": "12",
          "displayName": "12",
          "scheme": "12"
        }
      ],
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "ios": {
            "useFrameworks": "static",
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "myapp.ai.finance",
      "buildNumber": "3",
      "use_frameworks": "static",
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "associatedDomains": [
        "applinks:myapp.site"
      ],
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSUserTrackingUsageDescription": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you.",
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "v9wttpbfk9.skadnetwork"
          },
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "n38lu8286q.skadnetwork"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myapp.app",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "versionCode": 3,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./src/assets/icons/myapp.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "autoVerify": true,
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.site.site",
              "pathPrefix": "/records"
            }
          ],
          "category": [
            "BROWSABLE",
            "DEFAULT"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.INTERNET"
      ]
    },
    "resolutions": {
      "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.2",
      "@expo/prebuild-config": "~5.0.3",
      "expo-modules-autolinking": "~1.0.0"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--openssl-legacy-provider' next dev",
    "eas-build-pre-install": "npm config set legacy-peer-deps true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@burstware/expo-plaid-link": "^1.0.6",
    "@expo/config-plugins": "^5.0.4",
    "@expo/dev-server": "^0.1.123",
    "@expo/metro-config": "^0.5.1",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^17.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^6.4.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.14",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "expo": "~46.0.19",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-auth-session": "~3.7.4",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.3.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.0.1",
    "expo-device": "~4.3.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-random": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "~11.0.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "metro-core": "^0.73.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "node": "^19.6.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.7",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-web-webview": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "metro": "^0.73.3",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

eas.json

```
{
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug",
        "image": "latest"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "me@gmail.com",
        "ascAppId": "1234",
        "appleTeamId": "4321"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ditto - and. can't seem to find any docs to suggest what the error is

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: It’s been a while so I don’t fully remember but I think it had to do with some of the packages I had installed, I had to go through them one by one.